# Is an Object Pool pattern of shared_ptr possible?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, object-pooling

Is it possible to create an Object Pool of shared_ptr?
Sketching this in my head, I can see two ways of doing this but each have a flaw:

1. If T objects were stored in a reusable pool, the act of wrapping T in a shared_ptr on a get() request would result in the control block being re-allocated on the heap each time - therefore breaking the concept of an Object Pool.
2. If shared_ptr objects were stored in a reusable pool, the shared_ptr object must stop existing to initiate a custom deleter, and the custom deleter function only gets called with a T pointer. So there is nothing to recycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After exhaustive research and testing I have concluded that there is *no* legitimate way (as of C++11 or below) to make an object pool of reusable `shared_ptr<T>`'s directly. Certainly one can make a pool of `T` objects quite easily that serves `shared_ptr<T>`'s, but that results in heap allocation with every serve for the control block.

It *is* possible however to make an object pool of `shared_ptr<T>`'s indirectly (and this is the *only* way I have found to do it). By indirectly, I mean one must implement a custom 'memory pool' style allocator to store for reuse the memory released when `shared_ptr<T>` control blocks are destroyed. This allocator is then used as the third parameter of the `shared_ptr' constructor:

```
template< class Y, class Deleter, class Alloc > 
   std::shared_ptr( Y* ptr, Deleter d, Alloc alloc );
```

The `shared_ptr<T>` will still be constructed/allocated and deleted/de-allocated with heap memory - there is no way to stop it - but by making the memory reusable through the custom allocator, a deterministic memory footprint can be achieved.

Comment: `boost` offers such a memory pool custom allocator in its collection (if you are brave enough to go in that direction) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. But rather than making your pool return `std::shared_ptr<T>`, I would consider making it return [`boost::intrusive_ptr<T>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html). You could have `intrusive_ptr_release()` be responsible for freeing that block from the pool, and then it's just up to your users to construct `T` such that you can make an `intrusive_ptr<T>`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that I'm not using boost - just C++11.

Comment: You should be able to use a custom deleter to return the object to the pool. No need for boost in that case. Also have a look at std::allocate_shared if using a pool allocator would suite your need.

Comment: @Finn, as I understand things a custom deleter cannot be specified with either make_shared or allocate_shared.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the objects in a pool (e.g. as unique_ptr). The pool returns a shared_ptr on request. The custom deleter returns the data to the pool. A simple example of this is sketched here:

```
#ifndef __POOL_H_
#define __POOL_H_

#include <list>
#include <mutex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace common {

template<class T, bool grow_on_demand=true>
class Pool 
{
    public:
    Pool(const char* name_p, size_t n) 
        : mutex_m(), free_m(0), used_m(0), name_m(name_p) 
    {
        for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
           free_m.push_front( std::make_unique<T>() );
        }
    }

    const char* getName() const
    {
        return name_m.c_str();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> alloc()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_m);
        if (free_m.empty() )
        {
            if constexpr (grow_on_demand) 
            {
                free_m.push_front( std::make_unique<T>() );
            }
            else
            {
                throw std::bad_alloc();
            }
        }
        auto it = free_m.begin();
        std::shared_ptr<T> sptr( it->get(), [=](T* ptr){ this->free(ptr); } );
        used_m.push_front(std::move(*it));
        free_m.erase(it);
        return sptr;
    }


    size_t getFreeCount()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_m);
        return free_m.size();
    }

private:

    void free(T *obj)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_m);
        auto it = std::find_if(used_m.begin(), used_m.end(), [&](std::unique_ptr<T> &p){ return p.get()==obj; } );
        if (it != used_m.end())
        {
          free_m.push_back(std::move(*it));
          used_m.erase(it);
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("unexpected: unknown object freed.");
        }
    }

    std::mutex mutex_m;
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<T>> free_m;
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<T>> used_m;
    std::string name_m;
};

}

#endif /* __POOL_H_ */
```

By default, the pool adds new items if you allocate a new object from an empty pool (grow_on_demand=true).

- A new Pool creates `n` elements and adds them to the Pool (using the default constructor).
- With `mypool.alloc()` you can get an object from the pool.
- When the allocated object is not used any more, the shared_ptr is returned to the pool automatically (happens implicitly through `[=](T* ptr){ this->free(ptr); }` from within `alloc()`.