# How to re-cycle the Control Block allocated for std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

std::shared_ptr internally allocates(::new) a Control Block(Reference Count Object) in heap. When shared ptr's reference count becomes zero this Control block is deallocated(::delete).
For Performance reasons I need to re-cycle the memory allocated for this Control Block.

Accepted answer to Question [Is an Object Pool pattern of shared_ptr possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090302/is-an-object-pool-pattern-of-shared-ptr-possible), says a Custom Allocator should do the trick.
But it is NOT clear to me how the Allocator (Alloc) object created for Y does the allocation for Control Block

```
template< class Y, class Deleter, class Alloc > std::shared_ptr( Y* ptr, Deleter d, Alloc alloc );
```

Could someone please
point to an example of a custom allocator written for std::shared_ptr which re-cycles the Control Block object

OR

provide a partial code to re-cycle Control Block

OR

explain how an `Allocator<Y>` can allocate the Control Block for `std::shared_ptr template< class Y, class Deleter, class Alloc >`

NOTE : I am looking for a Solution that does NOT use boost::intrusive_ptr

Comment: There will be only one allocated block if you were to use `make_shared`/`allocate_shared`. Stick to those and there will be nothing to recycle. :-)

Comment: `shared_ptr` constructor taking an allocator would use [`allocator_traits::rebind_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) to obtain the allocator for some internal type it uses for the control block.

Comment: the disadvantage there is the managed object will ONLY be deleted when the last weak_pointer is destroyed.  There are advantages to keeping the control block as a separate object in which case having a pool of them will be a performance advantage and help prevent memory fragmentation.,  It would be nice to have two allocator methods one for the control block and one for the object.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  I have to test this it woudl be great if one can separately manage both the control block and the object allocation methods separately.

Answer (score -1):

you just need  to check out that there's no weak poitnters left (weak reference counter = 0) then do `ptr.reset()`.

Comment: are you saying shared_ptr<>::reset() does NOT delete the control block (i.e. kept with last shared_ptr to which heldvthe contained ptr) ?

Comment: Even if above is true, still Control Block is deleted if last shared_ptr is destroyed right ? (e.g. last shared_ptr being a local variable and going out of scope).

Comment: no. if related `weak_ptr` is alive cb is kept

Comment: So if there are no weak_ptr s, once last shared ptr is reset() , is cb deleted ? if so how is this re-cycling ?

Comment: yeah. just destroyed

Comment: Sorry, if it is destroyed(not re-cycled), could you pls explain how your "answer" answers my  question

Comment: sorry cannot understand what you said, pls clarify